# Is it possible to use inline comments for .ini files with PHP?

Tags: php, comments, ini

Is it possible and safe to use inline comments for .ini files with PHP?

I prefer a system where the comments are inline with the variables, coming after them.

Are the some gotchas concerning the syntax to be used?

Comment: your question is not clear. in order to get help your questions must be understandable, no body is in your head.

Answer (score 88):

[INI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Format) uses semicolon as a comment character. It accepts them anywhere in the file.

```
key1=value
; this is a comment
key2=value ; this is a comment too
```

Comment: Do you have any reference to the official documentation of the use as `;` besides as starting character?

Comment: While this question is about PHP, the Windows API does not support inline comments for INI files. I'm not sure whether PHP for Windows will use the Windows API to read INI files. In any case, Wikipedia is not a the best source.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about the built-in INI file parsing function, semicolon is the comment character it expects, and I believe it accepts them inline.

Comment: What is the syntax limitations allowed on the right side of the = sign? Does it follow the usual string quoting and escaping syntax, such as matching '', "" and some of the usual regex escape characters?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Why not try it and find out?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$ini = <<<INI
; this is comment
[section]
x = y
z = "1"
foo = "bar" ; comment here!
quux = xyzzy ; comment here also!
a = b # not a comment
INI;

$inifile = tempnam(dirname(__FILE__), 'ini-temp__');
file_put_contents($inifile, $ini);
$a = parse_ini_file($inifile, true);
if ($a !== false)
{
  print_r($a);
}
else
{
  echo "Couldn't read '$inifile'";
}

unlink($inifile);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [section] => Array
        (
            [x] => y
            [z] => 1
            [foo] => bar
            [quux] => xyzzy
            [a] => b # not a comment
        )

)
```

Note that PHP's INI parser does not support `#` for comments.

Comment: I don't think you need to write to a temp file; `parse_ini_string()` will do the trick http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php

Comment: parse_ini_string (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)